# maven module, Connect persistance.xml with Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, spring-integration

I realize an App which I have a project father and 4 project module:

```
  -persistance
  --META-INF/persistence
  --pom.xml
  -business
  --pom.xml
  -controller
  --pom.xml 
  -web
  -- pom.xml
```

SOLVED: src/resources/META-INF/persistance.xml

Thank you.

Comment: add  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>  and check

Comment: I have eclipselink, where do I add the provider?

Comment: ok fine add this line in  persistence.xml after persistence unit name<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider> -

Comment: let me know status after add this

Comment: same error:   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named p
 javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
 javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
 es.juan.app.model.GestionAlumnosImpl.<init>(GestionAlumnosImpl.java:18)
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: where did u place persistence.xml ?

Comment: persistence.xml should be in project/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: let me know the status

Comment: Fantastic!!!! I am forgot  add persistance xml to resources!!!! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your persistence.xml

```
project/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
```